# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '<>f__AnonymousType9`2[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting an error after executing a linq expression in C#. I can see the values in the where clause while debugging but not sure why i get null exception

Following is the error

```
'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '<>f__AnonymousType9`2[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]] get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'
```

The first steps I get the ids

```
var benchmarks = GetService<MANAGERSTRATEGY>().Where(x => x.ID == id).Select(x => new { x.BENCHMARK1_ID, x.BENCHMARK2_ID }).ToList();
```

The second step is I get the ids based on the values

```
    var indexPerformance = GetViewService<MV_INDEX_PERFORMANCE>().Where(x=>  x.IndexId == benchmarks[0].BENCHMARK1_ID || x.IndexId == benchmarks[0].BENCHMARK2_ID);
```

[image]

The value of the first parameter
[image]

The value of the second parameter
[image]

The model is for a materialised view in oracle

```
  public class MV_INDEX_PERFORMANCE : ViewEntity
    {

        [Column("INDEX_LIST_FIELD_ID")] public int IndexListFieldId { get; set; }
        [Column("TICKER")] public string Ticker { get; set; }
        [Column("INDEX_ID")] public int IndexId { get; set; }
        [Column("CCY_ID")] public int? CcyId { get; set; }
        [Column("CCY_CODE")] public string CcyCode { get; set; }
        [Column("FIELD_ID")] public int? FieldId { get; set; }
        [Column("FIELD_CODE")] public string FieldCode { get; set; }
        [Column("FIELD_NAME")] public string FieldName { get; set; }
        [Column("INDEX_NAME")] public string IndexName { get; set; }
        [Column("PRICE_DATE")] public DateTime PriceDate { get; set; }
        [Column("PRICE_DATE_ACTUAL")] public  DateTime PriceDateActual { get; set; }
        [Column("PRICE")] public int? Price { get; set; }
        [Column("MTD")] public int? Mtd { get; set; }
        [Column("MTD_MINUS_THREE")] public int? MtdMinusThree { get; set; }
        [Column("QTD")] public int? Qtd { get; set; }
        [Column("YTD")] public int? Ytd { get; set; }
        [Column("SI")] public  int? Si { get; set; }
    }
```

The GetViewService

```
public IViewService<X> GetViewService<X>() where X : ViewEntity, new()
    {
        return IoC.Resolve<IViewService<X>>();
    }
```

Where method in IViewService

```
 public IEnumerable<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            try
            {
                using (new TimedLogger(_perfLogger, GetCompletedText("Where")))
                {
                    return Authorize(_repo.Where(predicate).ToList(), AuthAccessLevel.Read);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though those values just look like int?s in your inspection tooltip, to display them VS is evaluating/traversing your anonymous type to get at the actual values to display to you.

The compiler needs *at compile-time* to construct an expression that does the same, and it will include similar logic in the expression so that it can be executed at run-time to get at the values.

You then pass the same predicate/expression through to your repository, where EF tries to generate SQL from the expression, and lacks the sophistication to be able to do so (the database model will have no awareness of your anonymous type), hence the part in the error about being unable to “create a store expression” (=SQL in this case). It’s just a limitation of the mapper; it can manage simple types fine but will struggle with this.

If you copy the 2 values out into local variables and use those in the predicate instead it should be fine.